# In android, BitmapFactory.decodeFile do not work

Tags: android

I use the following code to get a image in sd card, and then show the image by ImageView:

```
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgUri.getPath());
img.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

However, nothing is showed.
I had edit the AndroidManifest.xml in this way:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

But that does not work.
Now I know that the image in sd card did not be read by the program. How can I solve the problem?
Ps: The phone I use is RedMi 4X, the operating system is MIUI8.

Comment: Why don't you post your log error message?

Answer (score 1):

Because `file://` or `content://` makes it incorrect. Try this:

```
Uri uri;
Context context;
try {
    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(imgUri));
img.setImageBitmap(bmp);
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Or, better yet, use an image-loading library (Picasso, Glide, etc.).

Comment: I tried your method, but when the program is running, it will exit with error. What's more, the output of the img.getPath(); does not content the file:// or content://.